# How to change Blob Object width and height for each record crystal report?

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I have one crystal report in which detail section contains Blob object.
Now I am  passing Byte array for Image to report.

I have fixed height and width of Blob object in report and adjusting height and width of each image according to Blob object height and width with maintain aspect ratio.

Problem I am facing is, I want to set different height and width for each Blob object in report and report setting width and height of last image height and width and all images displaying with last image height and width.

Code That I am using to set Height and Width of Blob Object is

```
var imageObject = printWithImage.DetailSection2.ReportObjects.OfType<BlobFieldObject>().Where(w => w.Name.Equals("Image1")).SingleOrDefault();
            int width = image.Width;
            int height = image.Height;


            if (image.Width > 245)
            {
                width = 245;
                var val = decimal.Parse(width.ToString()) * aspectRadio;
                height = (int)val;
                if (height > 144)
                {
                    height = 144;
                    var val1 = decimal.Parse(height.ToString()) / aspectRadio;
                    width = (int)val1;
                }
                imageObject.Width = (int)(width * 15);
                imageObject.Height = (int)(height * 15);
            }
            else if (image.Height > 144)
            {
                height = 144;
                var val = decimal.Parse(height.ToString()) / aspectRadio;
                width = (int)val;
                if (width > 245)
                {
                    width = 144;
                    var val1 = decimal.Parse(width.ToString()) * aspectRadio;
                    height = (int)val1;
                }
                imageObject.Width = (int)(width * 15);
                imageObject.Height = (int)(height * 15);
            }
```

How can persists image width and height for each detail section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem By Set can Grow = True in Blob Object and set height and width of Blob Object same as Original height and width of Blob Object. And from viewmodel i have resizing image if image is grater then Blob Object size then reduce it with maintain aspect ratio